# getting source code of redirected http site via c# webclient

Tags: c#

I have problem with certain site - I am provided with list of product ID numbers (about 2000) and my job is to pull data from producer site. I already tried forming url of product pages, but there are some unknown variables that I can't put to get results. However there is search field so i can use url like this: http://www.hansgrohe.de/suche.htm?searchtext=10117000&searchSubmit=Suchen - the problem is, that given page display info (probably java script) and then redirect straight to desired page - the one that i need to pull data from.

is there any way of tracking this redirection thing?

I would like to put some of my code, but everything i got so far, i find unhelpful because it just download source of preregistered page.

```
public static string Download(string uri)
{

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    string s = client.DownloadString(uri);
    return s;

}
```

Also suggested answer is not helpfull in this case, because redirection doesn't come with http request - page is redirected after few seconds of loading http://www.hansgrohe.de/suche.htm?searchtext=10117000&searchSubmit=Suchen url

I just found solution, And since i'm new, and i have to wait few hours to answer my question, it will end up there:

I hope that other users will find it usefull:
{pseudocode}

```
webBrowser1.Navigate('url');

while (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri != 'url')
{
// wait
}
String desiredUri = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Please add your code and improve the post to stop the closure.

Comment: is it just me, or does this question sound a lot like "I'm trying to scrape a web-site that is putting up some resistance; please help me scrape them" - if you were *meant* to be doing this, the API would be clear and documented (and probably: not html)

Comment: basically yes - the given company supplied me with fist of their products, and prices as im their dealer - but im still missing description of those - i could spend whole week, retyping it word by word from catalog, or use some help from informatic science, and have it done in just few hours

Comment: I work for a company where were constantly fighting screen scrapers. We spend a lot of money developing systems for users to use only to see our hard work stolen by screen scraping services. Please don't do this!

Comment: Liam i understand that, screen scraping is delicate subject, and im sure that sometimes it can be used to stole copyrighted materials. In this particular case it is not matter, because data we get is nessesary to further advertise our partner products, and unfortunatelly our partner is providing that data only on paper. So Yes, im against screen scrapping overall, if its used to steal.
Best regards, JMW

Comment: In that case, work with your partner to develop a proper API to use.  Don't screen scrape.  You don't want to rewrite your application every time they update their website, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of page scraping. The short answer is "you can't do that." Not in the general case, anyway, and certainly not with WebClient. The problem appears to be that some Javascript does the redirection. And since all WebClient does is download the page, it's not even going to download the Javascript. Much less parse and execute it.

You *might* be able to do this by creating a program that uses the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class. You can have it load the page. It should do the redirect and then you can inspect the result, which should be the page you were looking for. I haven't actually done this, but it does seem possible.

Your other option is to fire up your Web browser's developer tools (like IE's F12 Developer Tools) and watch what's happening. You can then inspect the Javascript that's being executed as well as the modified DOM, and see where the redirect happens.

Yes, it's tedious work. But once you figure out the redirect for one page, you can probably generate the URL for the other pages you want automatically.

Comment: Jim - found a bit which didn't make sense to me; feel free to roll back if I've got the wrong end of what you meant :)

Comment: @Bridge: Thanks. I did mean "party", but I changed it to be more clear.